# Build partner.jar

Tags: soap-api, java, wsdl, partner-wsdl, enterprise-wsdl

I'm following the instruction on [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_steps_import_wsdl.htm).

When I tried with the `enterprise.wsdl` I was able to generate the `enterprise.jar` using `force-wsc-37.0.jar`, `js-1.7R2.jar` and  `ST-4.0.8.jar`.

Now I'm trying to generate the `partner.jar` but I'm getting this error:
`Error: Not possible to find neither load the main class com.salesforce.ws.tools.wsdlc`

I used the same command line to Enterprise and Partner. (`$ java -classpath force-wsc-37.0.jar:js-1.7R2.jar:ST-4.0.8.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc partner.wsdl partner.jar`)

Comment: Is the WSC Jar file (force-wsc-37.0.jar) in your working directory, or is it accessible via your `classpath`? It looks like you have the Rhino library as detailed in [Building the Partner.jar API file](http://sforcehacks.blogspot.co.nz/2013/04/building-partnerjar-api-file.html)

Comment: All the `.jar` files are in the same classpath, then I just go into the folder by `cd example` and try to run the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue.
My Maven was in version 2.2.1 and it required version 3.0 +. I just updated it and worked fine.

Thanks for who helped.

Comment: I am facing same issue when craeting Partner jar. I am not using Maven, it's a simple java project
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sforce.ws.codegen.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:48)
        at com.sforce.ws.codegen.Generator.compileTypes(Generator.java:136)
        at com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc.run(wsdlc.java:129)
How can I fix this?